# Why do I fail to launch codellama?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python

I cloned `https://github.com/facebookresearch/codellama.git` downloaded the 7B model, I created the virtual environment `my-venv`, activated it and installed the requirements, like so

```
python3 -m venv my-venv && mv codellama my-venv 
cd my-venv
source "bin/activate" &&
pip3 install -r codellama/requirements.txt
pip install -e .
```

When I I proceeded to launch the chat with
`torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_completion.py \ --ckpt_dir CodeLlama-7b/ \ --tokenizer_path CodeLlama-7b/tokenizer.model \ --max_seq_len 128 --max_batch_size 4`

```
> initializing model parallel with size 1
> initializing ddp with size 1
> initializing pipeline with size 1
/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/__init__.py:614: UserWarning: torch.set_default_tensor_type() is deprecated as of PyTorch 2.1, please use torch.set_default_dtype() and torch.set_default_device() as alternatives. (Triggered internally at ../torch/csrc/tensor/python_tensor.cpp:451.)
  _C._set_default_tensor_type(t)
[2023-12-03 13:32:24,787] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api: [ERROR] failed (exitcode: -9) local_rank: 0 (pid: 220150) of binary: /home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 346, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 806, in main
    run(args)
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 797, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 134, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/j/CS/large_language_models/my-venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 264, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError: 
=======================================================
example_completion.py FAILED
-------------------------------------------------------
Failures:
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>
-------------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2023-12-03_13:32:24
  host      : j-AERO-17-KC
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : -9 (pid: 220150)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 9 (SIGKILL) received by PID 220150
=======================================================
```

What may be happening here? How might I launch codellama chat?

P.S. My environment: Ubuntu Desktop LTS 22.04